# How to assign different static IP addresses to the same machine depending on its OS on a network?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, static-ip, router

I was wondering if it is possible, e.g. to assign/reserve one static IP to a computer when it's running windows and assign a second static IP to the same computer/MAC address when it's running Linux?

I have seen this been done for my computer under several university-wide networks. That is, the same NIC is assigned one stable IP for windows, and a different one for Linux. I don't know if it is just dynamic IP being remembered for a real long time, or something else is going on. But the university network is able to give me two specific IP's depending on the OS that is running.

My questions are,

1. What kind of network administration technology is used to differentiate OSes and assign IP's based on OS brands?
2. Can I (and how to) do the same on my own network using a router?

Thanks

Comment: I've edit the question. In general, it is interesting to know what kind of technology is used to differentiate OSes, and assign IP's to clients based on that. I think this is related to network admin, not how you change the settings of a single computer. Otherwise, I would have asked it in superuser.

Comment: This is not related to professional network or systems admin, as this is not something that we would ever need to do on a professionally-run network.

Comment: But this (the assignment of different IPs based on OS) is actually something university administrators do for thousands of computers. I've seen it done by administrators in almost every university I worked with. I don't see how that's not professionally run, and why shouldn't questions be asked about it here. If I remove the dd-wrt and home/network part, will this be an acceptable question?

Comment: It wouldn't help, because then you would get answers appropriate to the administrators of a university network, and not to your home network. You might try our sister site [su].

Comment: Even if I am not a university admin, would this question still be useful to univ admins, regardless of who asked it? Why is my occupation so important as to whether a question can be asked about network admin.

Comment: Static IPs would be the sensible thing. However, that would require a fair amount of manual setting up.

Answer (score 1):

I would change the MAC address in Linux, so that it was a different MAC than the windows partition. Then reserve the ip's for the 2 MAC's.

Comment: +1 Thanks, I will try that. I am interested though in how not to change the Linux Mac Address as the university admin didn't change my MAC address.